# In flutter dart how to search whole word in text

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi i want to search whole word contain in a string for example i want to search **bro** it should only return true if separate word bro found like **"Arjun bro"** and returns false for **"brodband"** im using contains method but that is not giving desired output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression To do so.

Following code help you more.

```
String search = 'Bro';
  String str = 'Breo Brother abcBro';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
              caseSensitive: false,
      caseSensitive: false,
    RegExp exp = new RegExp( "\\b" + search + "\\b", caseSensitive: false, ); 
    bool containe = exp.hasMatch(str);
    print(containe);
  }
```

Output:

```
  false
```

**Note:** 
correct first Bro in string then it will print true.
It is case insensitive, so to make sensitive again remove **caseSensitive: false**.

Comment: it returning false for "Arjun bro"

Comment: Thanks for answer worked by changing regular expression to

 RegExp exp = new RegExp(
      "\\b" + search + "\\b",
      caseSensitive: false,
    );

Comment: Not working for RegExp("\\b" + "א" + "\\b").hasMatch("א")